# Understanding domain registration and dns lookup

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, domain-registrar, domain-registration

I want to understand the process of how your domain gets queried from dns servers after purchasing a domain. I have not yet tried hosting and have no plans atm but I am eager to learn.

Here is what I have deduced so far (some are still speculations as I could not find the exact details of how it works). First, after purchasing a domain from the registrar, you will configure the DNS servers that will be authoritative for your domain in the registrar's DB. I speculate that aside from the names of the dns servers you will also configure the IP addresses of your name servers so a dns lookup on the registrar's DNS servers can give the IP of your authoritative name servers. Also, a whois look up for your domain would return the name servers you have configured.

Now that people have a way to learn your nameservers ip address, they can query your own authoritative name servers for the ip address of your domains and sub domains.

I know it is much complicated than that, but what I want to clarify is how domain registration works and how TLD name servers KNOW who your name servers are so they can redirect requests for your domain to your name servers. At the moment I think that configuring your name servers in your registrar's db also configures the TLD name servers and the whois database. Is this correct? Or is there a separate process? I am confused whether or not the domain registrar also handles the TLD name servers.

Comment: It would be nice to know why I got a downvote.

Comment: Your intentions are good, but we get a massive number of poorly researched questions on SF. Since our focus is on business environments, we tend to be trigger happy if the question does not demonstrate expertise in a subject matter and is sidestepping proper education/training on the topic. I recommend purchasing a book if you're truly interested in the nuts and bolts of how DNS operates from the top down. It gets complicated!

Answer (score -1):

Domain Name Servers work by communicating with the actual company ICANN -the international body that controls and regulates the internet's DNS- central servers to map your IP address to your FQDN. The DNS registrars such as GoDaddy and Dreamhost are fully registered with ICANN as approved registrars. That's why when you checkout at the end of your website registration you notice a ICANN fee. Registars such as GoDaddy pay ICANN millions of dollars so it can be TLD.